# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am getting below error when i am trying do sorting.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
public static string SortColumn    
{
  get
    {
      return HttpContext.Current.Session["SORT_COLUMN"].ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["SORT_COLUMN"] = value;
    }
}
```

please help me on this...

Comment: Is the getter or setter throwing? I assume its the getter. So maybe you should assure that there is something written to "SORT_COLUMN" before trying to retrieve it?

Answer (score 4):

`Session["SORT_COLUMN"]` can return `null` and you can't call *something* on *nothing*, so `ToString` would fail.

Also, `HttpContext.Current` could return `null`, meaning you can't access `Session` - this can happen if you're trying to access the context from the global.asax code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the Session variable before you access the getter. Otherwise you have to check:

```
return HttpContext.Current.Session["SORT_COLUMN"] != null ? 
       HttpContext.Current.Session["SORT_COLUMN"].ToString() : string.Empty
```

Comment: Thank you Slfan..How can write code for that please send me code

Comment: @Indra: either put this code into the getter or initialize the Session value on Session_Start event in global.asax